# Youtube Live Stream embed code shows "Live stream offline"

Tags: youtube, embed, youtube-iframe-api

I have a channel in youtube and want to show in my website the live stream videos, if I have a live stream in youtube.

I have followed instructions from https://www.youtube.com/features and enabled both "Live Stream" and "Embed live streams" options, but every time I have a live stream the youtube shows me "Live stream offline" on player.

I have embed the iframe in my website like this

```
<iframe width="650" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=myChannelId" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

also I have tried setup this gaming url

```
<iframe width="650" height="400" src="https://gaming.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=myChannelId" allow="autoplay" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And also I cannot enable "Monetization" from features, because it is disabled and not available from our country.

Can anybody help me to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Same as you minus the allow autoplay property.

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="602" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=MyChannelId" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

There is a brief delay, and sometimes you have to refresh the page.